# How can I apply CSS to webparID?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, development, javascript, css

how can I apply css to webpart ID. I have the following webpart:

`webpartid="5a399f4c-f605-409c-8e3c-55993af60c9a"` I need to apply css only for this webpartID

How can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: By learning to use CSS selectors: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most often there are no IDs.

And hardcoding IDs (generated by SharePoint)  in CSS rules will get you in trouble sometime in the future.

When you add,(re)move other WebParts the IDs can change.

Learn how to use CSS selectors to target with metadata used in other attributes.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Although not perfect, the webpart guid is better

```
DIV[webpartid^='5a399f4c'] {
                             background:pink
                           }
```

Targets all DIVs (most likely only one)  with a webpartid **starting with** 5a399f4c

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_begin.asp

Answer (score 1):

Inspect the webpart after it has rendered on the page. Look for it's [element ID](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/id-html-attribute/), then use that to apply styles.

Afterwards you will be able to drop css onto the page to alter it:

```
<style>
#RenderedWebpartID
{
   /* css attributes here */
}
</style>
```